# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'admin'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

I have this new remote job, where I had to clone all the code from a repository, and I have to make an export of the database from MySQL hosted in RDS.

The first problem is that when I set up the configuration to start the app, it raise an error telling me this:

`Run Configuration Error: Broken configuration due to unavailable plugin or invalid configuration data.`

The other thing is that I already have the data dumped and set up in my local storage (the app works this way, is no longer using AWS Cloud) but when I try to do an `python manage.py migrate` , this error comes up...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\Documents\App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\Documents\App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\Documents\App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\Documents\App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\Documents\App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Tony-App\Documents\App\venv\lib\site-packages\liststyle\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from admin import ListStyleAdminMixin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'admin'
```

Comment: is `django-liststyle` a dependency you are using?

Comment: Yes, do you think the problem comes from that dependency?

Comment: it is very likely. Make sure it has been installed, and also make sure that you have added this dependency to the `INSTALLED_APPS` as ```INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'liststyle',
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
}```

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'liststyle',
    'grappelli.dashboard',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'colorful',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'pipeline',
    'nocaptcha_recaptcha',
    'storages',
    'rosetta',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
   
)`

Comment: These are all the apps installed

Comment: I just added an answer to your question, check my third point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `django-liststyle` is a dependency in your project, so make sure it has been installed.

```
py -m pip install django-liststyle
```

Second, make sure to add that package to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'liststyle',
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
}
```

Third, I think the error you are getting is because of the way you are importing `ListStyleAdminMixin`. This should be the correct way to import it:

```
from liststyle.admin import ListStyleAdminMixin
```

Comment: Thanks man, you solve that problem, it raises another but it has to be with MySQL, I think I configure that wrong.